# Can't fix MBR after trying everything

Tags: windows-8.1, mbr

- OS: windows 8.1, Kali Linux
- CPU : AMD A4 quad core
- Brand/mode: Toshiba satellite
- 4 GB of ram
- UEFI is disabled

What happened:

So here is how it started. I installed Kali Linux on my computer but I accidently midified the MBR with grub. So I went to fix it by using the Windows 8.1 disk and in command prompt i typed:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
```

Operation was successfull.

I rebooted to find nothing but this:

[image]

I tried all the fixes I knew, here is the feedback:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
```

Operation successful // doesn't do squat

```
bootrec /fixboot
```

Same thing as the previous command

```
bootrec /rebuildBCD
```

Found windows on volume 1 but fails to add it to boot list

The requested system device cannot be found.

```
Bcdedit
```

The boot configuration data store could not be opened.
The requested system device cannot be found.

`Chkdsk` was able to run on `c:\` but didn't find anything particular (if I remember correctly). Start-up repair can't find the error.

when i try to refresh my PC:

> the drive where windows is installed is locked. Unlock the drive and
>   try again.

when i try to reset my PC:

> unable to reset your PC, a required drive partition is missing.

At this point I don't mind loosing everything, but try to avoid if possible. I'd like to remind that Windows 8 was preinstalled on my laptop and I do not have a serial.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Since you have both Windows 8.1 and Kali Linux installed.  The Windows Boot Manager could work but it is very fiddly and mysterious in 8.1.  So this will be a how-to for recovering GRUB2 onto the MBR of the hard drive and using it to boot either Kali Linux or Windows 8.1.

**Getting the ISO onto a bootable media**

You will want to get the stable ISO for Rescatux. After you downloaded it, get yourself either an empty CDROM or a USB flash drive you can erase the contents of or backup.  If you're using a flash drive.  you will want to use a program such as Rufus to put the ISO on it.  Rufus is great because it detects pretty much all the time which drive is your USB flash drive.  It doesn't even need an installer.

As for a CDROM, a program such as Imgburn should do the trick.  I think Windows 7 had built-in image burning but I can't be sure.  Using Imgburn and Rufus is pretty straightforward and there are dozens of tutorials online to show you where the right buttons are.

**Booting the media**

Now that you have your CDROM or USB drive ready.  Since I have a toshiba satellite on Windows 8 too, I know everything about that laptop.  You'll want just as usual to quickly press F12 on bootup to get the menu.  if you're unsure, plug the usb drive into the usb 2.0 port on the left side of the laptop.  That one always works.  then on the menu choose USB or CDROM depending on your type of media.

When you're at the Rescatux boot menu.  just press enter and after a few moments of booting.  you should get to Rescapp.

**What to do in Rescapp**

Now that you got here.  the end is not very further away.  Now in the Rescapp window, click on "Restore Grub" then click again on "Restore Grub!!!".  at that point, you should get a window asking you to choose a partition.  Since you have linux installed I'm going to make a guess on the partition scheme and tell you which one to use.

- sda1 Kali Linux
- sda2 someting else

of all the partitions listed, click on the one that has the name of your Linux distribution as label then click "OK".

Now, a new window will show up asking you on which drive to install GRUB.  since this is a laptop, you only have one hard drive thus making this step very straightforward. just select the drive sda (it should appear at a couple hundred gigabytes anyway!) then click on "OK".

The next window that shows up, just make sure that sda is first in the list and it should be alright. then click "OK".  It'll take it's fine time and when it's done, you will get a window telling you GRUB was successfully installed.  you can now reboot and you should be able to get into bot Kali Linux and Windows 8.1 using GRUB at startup.

Comment: Can you include that process in your answer by chance

Comment: I could include it but the situation varies for each system configuration.  But I'll try to add explanation.

Comment: We expect more than a link that's why I asked

Comment: I read the wizard and it seems to only restore grub, not MBR... Also it looks a little confusing

Comment: The new edit made it clear, will try and report back.

Comment: So Rescatux didn't helped recover my grub but it did made me boot into linux, which I then proceed and Installed Grub/update grub with success, But I still need to be able to boot into Windows 8.

Comment: Well, progress...  So, I'd say maybe try rebooting into Rescatux but choose the Super GRUB2 Disk option in the menu instead. there should be a menu to try booting into windows, there should be one that works.  when you find it, reboot again and go back to that option but press (I think it's E) to look at the commands used to boot into windows.  note especially the lines that contain some kind of "hd0,1" or "hd0,0".  and tell them to me, I'll give you an explanation to bring Windows back manually in the GRUB2 boot menu.

Comment: Okay, So the following happened.... I have no idea why and how.

I tried what you said and every option said something like "can't boot from BIOS try booting Sga2 from EFI." I knew what EFI was and activated it from BIOS. Next boot skipped the boot order and went directly to windows. I didn't got into my Rescatux menu, It simply went to windows. Please, I am so confused right now

Comment: OK, you didnt uninstall the uefi windows install and to install linux you just turned off uefi boot and partitionned the drive under linux.  so basicly, your linux install is MBR while your Windows install is UEFI...  that means you have to reinstall at least one of them and make sure they're both uefi or non uefi.  not uefi is a little weird on the windows side but gives you freedom of whatever linux you want to install.  as for UEFI, Windows works great as usual but you'll only be able to install certain major distros like linux mint, fedora or ubuntu.

Comment: If I decide to reinstall windows 8.1 under non uefi it's get weird..... how?

Will I get performance issue?

Comment: It'll go fine, no real performance hit but mostly startup times and ridiculously low resolution during setup process.

Answer (score -1):

Download Slacko Puppy 5.5 or above and run from ISO.

In the menus there is a grub4dos installation wizard which should find both your kali install and your windows 8.1 - Make sure you understand what drive you are installing to, and burn a CD - don't USB install Slacko.

Comment: Is there a way to install with usb? My only other laptop with w.8.1 doesn't have an optical drive.

Comment: Try using YUMI USB boot creator, and make sure you are fixing the MBR of the internal HDD not the USB.